# Why is $H(E) = H(P_e)$ in the proof of Fano's inequality?

Tags: proof-explanation, information-theory

On page $17$ of these [Lecture Notes](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Eyxie77/ece587/Lecture4.pdf) (theorem on page 15, and section of question copied in image below), why is $H(E) = H(P_e)$?  Specifically, $E = \{1 \text{ if } \hat X \neq X, \space  0 \text{ if } \hat X = X\}$ and $P_e = p(\hat X \neq X)$.

Shouldn't we have:

> $H(E) = -p(\hat X \neq X) \log p(\hat X \neq X) - p(\hat X = X) \log p(\hat X = X)$

and

> $H(P_e) = H(p(\hat X \neq X)) = \sum_{\hat x, x} p(\hat x, x) \log p(\hat x \neq x)$

What am I misunderstanding?

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_e = p(\hat{X}\neq X)$, which is a number (not a probability distribution). By a slight abuse of notation, for $p\in[0,1]$ the entropy $H(p)$ is the binary entropy function, which is the entropy of the Bernoulli r.v. with parameter $p$:
$$
H(p) = -p \log p - (1-p)\log(1-p)
$$
see [lecture 2, p.8](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Eyxie77/ece587/Lecture2.pdf) for confirmation. *(I personally hate this notation, and would encourage you to use $h(p)$ for the bianry entropy, since it's a function $h\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, not taking an r.v. or probability distribution as argument.)*

So here, indeed,
$$\begin{align}
H(P_e) 
&= -P_e\log P_e - (1-P_e)\log(1-P_e)\\
&= -p(\hat{X}\neq X)\log p(\hat{X}\neq X) - p(\hat{X}= X)\log p(\hat{X}= X)\\
&= H(E)
\end{align}$$